# Hiding/graying out closed and on-hold questions in list?

Tags: support

Often times there are questions that are picked up by my favorite tags list or I am able to answer, but they are closed or have been put on hold. Since I am not high enough reputation to do anything about this, closed questions are essentially noise in my "personalized" question list.

Is there any way I can gray these closed questions out or otherwise hide them?

[image: Example]

Comment: Pretty sure this is by design. You *can* do something about questions that are On Hold right now; you can suggest edits to improve them and make them suitable for reopening. Of course, not every question can be saved in this way, but as you gain reputation, you'll gain the ability to cast reopen votes (if a question is suitable for reopening thanks to an edit, or was incorrectly closed), or vote to delete. The site is designed to place opportunities for you to participate in moderation and improving content in front of you all the time. You are, of course, free to not take advantage of them.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz What about on SO, then? There you can select tags to "hide", and closed questions are very infrequently shown.

Comment: You can hide tags on Arqade just like you can on SO. And SO probably shows closed questions infrequently just because they have so many open questions and so much activity.

Comment: Hmm, well at least how can I get closed questions to not be highlighted?

Comment: Do you mean the highlighting that comes along with a favourite tag? That's going to happen on every question that features a favourite tag of yours, even if  they are closed/on hold, and cannot be removed just for the on-hold questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do much to hide closed or on hold questions from the front page. This is **by design**.

Arqade (and the whole of Stack Exchange) is built on the premise that the content posted & presented here is *community moderated*: you, me and everyone else decide what is and isn't a valid question. *

For this reason, you are shown closed/on hold questions because there's a chance that you may be able to clarify them (and with more rep, actively vote on them) such that they can be reopened into productive members of the question society.

The reason that the question is showing highlighted is because you've **favourited** one or more tags that it uses. Again this is by design: who better to review & attempt to salvage a question then someone who plays the game & follows the tag? **^**

Here's some things you *could* do when you see closed/on-hold questions:

- Ignore them. Fairly obvious, but there's plenty more you could do.
- Vote on them.

  - Questions with absolutely no salvageability (such as spam posts) get removed from the front page automatically given enough downvotes.
  - Remember, you can vote up as well, if you think a question is clear and useful!
- Edit them.

  - Some questions are just blatantly off-topic and will be deleted in due course, but editing 'On hold' questions will auto-push them into the 'Reopen' [review queue](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review) for people with more than 3k rep to vote on.
  - Remember to preserve the original point of the question as much as possible. Clarify the OPs meaning without putting words in their mouth.
- Browse the [Newest Questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) tab instead.

  - This tab only shows new questions, unlike the main page that show bumped/active questions (edited, modified, answered, and [Community-User poked](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) questions count as active).
  - Note that you won't **avoid** closed/on-hold questions this way, but generally these questions will still be fresh and not closed straight away.

<sub>* More rep, more trust, [more moderation tools you have access to](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). Make a difference where you can and with the tools you've got.

**^** Probably someone whose [earned a badge](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=Tags&filter=all) for answering questions in that tag, but that's neither here nor there.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer... although I seem to often be a downvote magnet on the Meta sites.

Comment: @oldmud0 - meta votes generally mean (dis)agreement rather than a reflection on quality - I wouldn't worry about it too much. :-)